# Checking closeness of coordinates in one group with another

Tags: python, algorithm, nearest-neighbor

I have two groups of coordinates:

1. `{(x1,y1),..(xn,yn)}`
2. `{(w1,z1),..(wn,zn)}`

and I would like to match each pair in group 2 to the pair in group 1 to which it is closest. My groups are large so the search needs to be efficient.
Any advice on setting this up would be appreciated. Moreover, if I instead had 2 groups with Group 1 = `{(x1,y1,z1),..(xn,yn,zn)}` and Group 2 = `{(u1,v1, w1),..(un,vn,wn)}`, how will my answer differ? Also, considering that my groups are too big to store on a computer, then, any suggestions for overcoming this issue would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't think you can do much better than calculating the distances for every combination and checking those for the smallest ones.

That requires you to calculate the distance `n` times each for `n` objects, so it will take `n^2` calculations just to get the distances. If your dataset is truly as huge as you say, then you can basically forget about those calculations finishing within the next few thousand years.

Comment: What do you know already about the range and distribution of the points?

Comment: @Prune Hi -- nothing is known particularly about the range and distribution of the coordinates. The efficient-search algorithm should work for any user-specified value of n. And how to deal with extremely large data sets. Would appreciate any working example for this. thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a [KDTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree): this algorithm allows to efficiently find the nearest neighbor significantly reducing the number of comparisons. The "KD" stands for "k-dimensional" meaning it can tackle data in an arbitrary number of dimensions (to answer your last question).

You can build a tree using one of the list and then for each element of the other list query for the nearest element. Scipy provides an [implementation for ktrees](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.KDTree.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Can you give a small minimum working example that can generalize to any coordinates of size n? And also any advice on my follow up questions?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on his own. A good way to show this effort is to include a [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Check the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), especially [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).